# How can i run a C# program from Qt C++ program?

Tags: c#, .net, qt, frameworks, qprocess

I have a program written in **C#** (.net framework 4.0) and i have a main program written in **Qt C++**, i need to run this program (C# program) from my main program, the problem is if i use QProcess to run it, nothing happens, i used waitForStarted and waitForFinished members functions of Qprocess but already timeout.

I tried Qprocess (start()), system().
Here is what i tried:

```
QProcess p;
p.start(qApp->applicationDirPath()+"/control.exe",{"0000"},QIODevice::ReadWrite);
p.waitForFinished();

QFile fff(qApp->applicationDirPath()+"/control.csv");
if(!fff.exists())

{
   /*Error control.csv not exists*/
}
```

control.exe extracts data from a datagridView and store it in control.csv file, but the csv file is not created while control.exe works perfectly when i run it from windows console.
How can i run it from Qt C++ program?

PS: my C# program is a console application.

Thank for helping me.

Comment: Please show your code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Should be no problem with `QProcess`.

Comment: Connect to the [other `QProcess` signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#signals) and check the responses.  Also, how long does your `C#` app. take to run?  `QProcess::waitForFinished` only waits for 30 seconds by default and you never check its return value.  Does the `C#` app. definitely create the `csv` file under `qApp->applicationDirPath()`?  Creating it under the current working directory would be more usual (probably?).

Comment: @G.M. yes csv file is created in the same folder.

i have let a default value for waitForFinished (30 seconds) and always timedout.

Comment: "How can i run a C# program from Qt C++ program?" - Same as you'd run *any other* program written in *any other* language. The fact that the target program was written in C# is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After effort and perseverance, I managed to find the problem.
This line had to be changed

```
File.WriteAllText("control.csv", string.Join("\n", rows));
```

By this one

```
File.WriteAllText(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"control.csv", string.Join("\n", rows));
```

I already run it using **QProcess** object in Qt.

Indeed, I must specify the whole path using `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` where to store control.csv file, I thought it will be created near the C# program.

I noticed one think, the program is extremly slow to find the automationElement object, it takes more than 20 seconds.